# Plotting Frequency Spectrum using Matlab with hold function

Tags: matlab, plot, spectrum, spectrogram

Suppose I have successfully generated a Single-sided Power spectrum as follows:

```
X_mags = abs(fft(signal));
bin_vals = [0 : N-1];
fax_Hz = bin_vals*fs/N;
N_2 = ceil(N/2);
plot(fax_Hz(1:N_2), 20*log10(X_mags(1:N_2)));`
```

now I want to plot a second graph on top of the first one:

```
hold on;
```

Lastly I perform an LPC analysis on the signal and calculate the frequency response.
The frequency response should be plotted on top of the Power spectrum, so:

```
[a, g] = lpc(signal,N);
[h,f] = freqz(b,a,N,fs);
plot(?);
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the parameters are all correctly given, how should I write the plot function for having a correct display of the frequency response? A simple plot(f) doesn't work.

Can someone explain why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `plot(f)` tries to plot frequency vector, isn' t it?

Check the code below:

```
X_mags   = abs(fft(signal));
bin_vals = [0 : N-1];
fax_Hz   = bin_vals*fs/N;
N_2      = ceil(N/2);

[a, g]   = lpc(signal,N);
[h, f]   = freqz(b, a, N, fs);

figure,

hold on,
plot(f, 20*log10(abs(h)), 'r');
plot(fax_Hz(1:N_2), 20*log10(X_mags(1:N_2)));
title('Frequency Spectrum');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); 
ylabel('Amplitude (dB)');
legend('Frequency Response', 'Single-sided Power spectrum')
```

Btw, there is a MATLAB function `db()` for decibel calculation. That might be useful.

Comment: I tried it but the plot of the lpc is untill fs/2? What is the reason of it?

Comment: And There is a command like that: `plot(fax_Hz(1:N_2), 20*log10(X_mags(1:N_2)));`

Comment: I know, so that I have a single side of the power spectrum. But I do not use N_2 for the lpc, so why is it affected by it?
EDIT: nevermind, because of the to low order of the FIR of the LPC. By increasing the prediction order, I get better results (which is logical). Though is it pure coincidence that if N=2 the frequency response is untill fs/2? :)

Comment: Oh sorry. That is caused by `freqz()` function. It says **In all cases, the frequency response is evaluated at N points equally spaced around the upper half of the unit circle. If N isn't specified, it defaults to 512.** You can add `'whole'` to `freqz()` function as an argument..

Comment: I just figured the same indeed. Thanks Mehmet :)

Answer (score 0):

The response `h` is complex, so you'll want to get the magnitude of the response via multiplication by its complex conjugate.:

```
plot(f, 10*log10(h.*conj(h)));
```

Note the use of 10*log10 because the operation above squares the amplitude response held in `h`.

Or, if you're less interested in being pedantic about working with complex numbers, you could just take the absolute value of the complex values, being sure to 20*log10 because the `abs` does not square the values

```
plot(f, 20*log10(abs(h)));
```